# How to enter a location name while creating a bucket using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

Is there a way to enter a location name while creating a bucket in boto? The location name I want to use is not available in the `Location` object in boto.

In boto3 I can do this by:

```
s3.create_bucket(Bucket=uploadbucket,
    CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': 'my-location'})
```

However, I am looking for a way to do same in boto. I want a way to specify location as a string and not depend on the `Location` object. Even when I specify `us-east-1` it doesn't work and says "the specified location-constraint is not valid"

```
>>> import boto
>>> conn = boto.connect_s3()
>>> conn.create_bucket('mybucket', location="us-east-1")
```

Comment: Does [`create_bucket`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.create_bucket) take a `location` argument?  It looks like you need to supply a `CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': "us-east-1"}` argument.

Comment: That is true for boto3. not boto

Answer (score 2):

`us-east-1` is `DEFAULT` or empty string.

```
conn.create_bucket('mybucket', location=boto.s3.connection.Location.DEFAULT)
```

or

```
conn.create_bucket('mybucket')
```

It will work for other regions like `us-west-1`.

```
conn.create_bucket('mybucket', location="us-west-1")
```

For more locations:
[S3 Locations](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.connection.Location)